# How do I format my export to excel workbook in microsoft.office.interop.excel?

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, gridview

I have this export function that allows me to export 2 grid views into 2 separated worksheets in one excel.

But my problems are:

1. How can I have a usual popup window like usual download when I click on export button to prompt user to OPEN, SAVE AS, CANCEL of the download instead of saving it to a specific location (currently what I am doing in my codes)?
2. How can I set a code to enable wraptext = true for all my cells and also auto format the column height and width to fixed all the text so that it does not show ###### for date as an example when column width is too small when excel is opened.

protected void EXPORT_BUTTON_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
// creating new WorkBook within Excel application
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook workbook  =  app.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);

```
String DT1 = "Data table 1";
String DT2 = "Data table 2";

ExportToExcel(app, workbook, Gridview1, DT1, 1);

ExportToExcel(app, workbook, Gridview2, DT2, 2);   

}
public void ExportToExcel(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Application app, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook workbook, GridView gridview, string SheetName, int sheetid)
{

// see the excel sheet behind the program
app.Visible = true;

// get the reference of first sheet. By default its name is Sheet1.
// store its reference to worksheet

worksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)workbook,Worksheets.Add();

// changing the name of active sheet
worksheet.Name = SheetName;

// storing header part in Excel
for (int i = 1; i < gridview.Columns.Count + 1; i++)
{
    worksheet.Cells[1, i] = gridview.Columns[i - 1].HeaderText;
}



// storing Each row and column value to excel sheet
for (int i = 0; i < gridview.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < gridview.Columns.Count; j++)
    {
        worksheet.Cells[i + 2, j + 1] = gridview.Rows[i].Cells[j].Text.ToString();
    }
}
//save the application

workbook.SaveAs(@"C:\Users\test\Desktop\Test\" + datetime.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy_hh-mm-ss") + ".xls", Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
            }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify the path of the excel file to save to a virtual path as follows

```
workbook.SaveAs(@"C:\Users\test\Desktop\Test\" + datetime.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy_hh-mm-ss") + ".xls", Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
```

change this to

```
workbook.SaveAs(@"~/ExcelFiles/Filename.xlsx" + datetime.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy_hh-mm-ss") + ".xls", Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
```

Try the following code for displaying save as dialog

```
String FileName = "FileName.xlsx";
String FilePath = "~/ExcelFiles/FileName.xlsx"; 
System.Web.HttpResponse response = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response;
response.ClearContent();
response.Clear();
response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + FileName + ";");
response.TransmitFile(FilePath);
response.Flush();
response.End();
```

Comment: Hi I received this error Microsoft Excel cannot access the file 'C:\Users\testacc\Documents\~\ExcelFiles\DCA76310'. There are several possible reasons:

• The file name or path does not exist. at workbook.                          SaveAs(@"~/ExcelFiles/Filename.xlsx" + datetime.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy_hh-mm-ss") + ".xls", Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);

Comment: Hi Ramesh, I would like to thank you for your help all these while. In addition to this question that yet to be solve for the time being,  I do have a additional important question for my export function in another post located here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33161193/how-do-i-export-ajaxcontroltookkit-tabpanel-contentswhich-consist-of-multiple-c   I hope you can help me out on this thanks a lot:)

Comment: Hi Sorry as I have no idea regarding exporting chart to excel

Comment: How do I solve the error for the pop up dialogue? do you have any idea?

Comment: anywhere in the code if you specify the path "c:\users\testacc\documents", remove it and everywhere use "~/" to get relative path of your website and it may solve the issue.

Comment: I do have 2 workbook.save as because I would like to save directly into my server and another one to allow user to choose the path they would like to save. is it possible?

Comment: but in my 1st saveas it does not consist of /documents/ so im not sure where they get this path from

Comment: please post your code as it is so that I can verify and suggest any changes needed

Comment: Hi I have update my codes in --->> please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33146325/how-do-i-add-in-an-save-dialogue-function-in-my-export-to-excel-codes. Will reply on Monday thanks a lot.  This post is abit messy already. sorry.

Comment: Please refer to my question description as well. thanks alot

Comment: Hi, can you take a look at this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33213123/how-do-i-change-my-codes-from-office-interop-excel-to-openxml-sdk if you are able to help me out. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Excel.Worksheet worksheet =(Excel.Worksheet)workbook.Worksheets["Sheet" + sheetid];
```

Comment: Hi I have updated my codes according to your solution. Now I am able to populate the Gridview1 thanks . However Gridview2 worksheet created and populated thus I received the same error upon taking sheetid 2. Hope you can help me out on this thanks

Answer (score 1):

as specified by Laxmikant modify the code of your method "ExportToExcel" as follows.

```
public void ExportToExcel(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Application app, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook workbook, GridView gridview, string SheetName, int sheetid)
{

// see the excel sheet behind the program
app.Visible = true;

worksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)workbook.Worksheets.Add();

// changing the name of active sheet
worksheet.Name = SheetName;

// storing header part in Excel
for (int i = 1; i < gridview.Columns.Count + 1; i++)
{
    worksheet.Cells[1, i] = gridview.Columns[i - 1].HeaderText;
}

// storing Each row and column value to excel sheet
for (int i = 0; i < gridview.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < gridview.Columns.Count; j++)
    {
        worksheet.Cells[i + 2, j + 1] = gridview.Rows[i].Cells[j].Text.ToString();
    }
}
```

I removed these two lines of code and now there is no need of the parameter "Sheetid"

```
Excel.Worksheet worksheet =(Excel.Worksheet)workbook.Worksheets["Sheet" + sheetid];
worksheet = workbook.ActiveSheet;
```

Hope this will solve your issue

Comment: Hi Ramesh Babu, I have updated my questions. please take a look thanks .

Comment: Verify the answer I posted to display save as dialog.

Comment: sorry what are you trying mean? Pleasee refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33146325/how-do-i-add-in-an-save-dialogue-function-in-my-export-to-excel-codes in my new post thanks

Comment: I posted another answer in the same post to display save as dialog. Please have a look at it.

Comment: Hi I have update my codes in --->> please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33146325/how-do-i-add-in-an-save-dialogue-function-in-my-export-to-excel-codes. Will reply on Monday thanks a lot.  This post is abit messy already. sorry.

Answer (score 0):

you haven't added worksheet in Workbook

try below code

worksheet = (Excel._Worksheet)oXL.Worksheets.Add();

worksheet.Name = SheetName;

set your headers using rangs

```
  string[] colNames = new string[gv.Columns.Count];

  int col = 0;

  foreach(gvvolumns dc in GridView.Columns)
    colNames[col++] = dc.ColumnName;

  char lastColumn = (char)(65 + dtProducts.Columns.Count - 1);

  oSheet.get_Range("A1", lastColumn + "1").Value2 = colNames;
  oSheet.get_Range("A1", lastColumn + "1").Font.Bold = true;
  oSheet.get_Range("A1", lastColumn + "1").VerticalAlignment 
        = Excel.XlVAlign.xlVAlignCenter;
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. I tried adding worksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)workbook.Worksheets.Add(); replacing oXL with workbook as I believe it should be so. But I still receive the same error at the same line Excel.Worksheet worksheet =(Excel.Worksheet)workbook.Worksheets["Sheet" + sheetid]; where sheeted = 2

Comment: what is the purpose of Excel.Worksheet worksheet =(Excel.Worksheet)workbook.Worksheets["Sheet" + sheetid] .... worksheet is already added you can add your stuff directly to worksheet object which is already added in Workbook

Comment: That is for me to take in the ID to take the gridview1 and gridview2. please advice thanks

Comment: is that required to create xlsx or just for your understanding?  If it is only for understanding then try something else

Comment: The code is required. Anyway I received error at worksheet.Cells[1, i] = gridview.Columns[i - 1].HeaderText; with the implementation of your codes. I have problem populating gridview2 header. But Im not sure why as since it works for gridview1 but why error in gridview2? I have updated my codes in this question as well

Comment: In that case its not really dynamic as you set the specific range because both of my gridviews do not have the same number of columns